# What happens when using a cellphone when charging?

Tags: battery, charging

What happens when a phone is being used with the charger connected?

Will it take power from charger and save the battery usage?

OR

At one end, the charger keeps charging the battery and at the other 
end, phone discharges the battery simultaneously?

(I am using Sony Xperia SP with Android 4.2.1)

Answer (score 4):

As using the device also uses some power, the device cannot "charge with the normal speed" at the same time. It will however primarily use the external power source for its consumption. Depending on whether you "consume" more power than the source can feed, either it compensates by taking whatever is needed additionally *from* the battery, or feeds whatever is left *to* it.

A side effect described in the other answers already is true, however: the device will get "warmer" this way. I already described that in [another answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/27742/16575):

> Recommendation for cold days to get warm fingers: Take your device with both hands, plug in the charger. Now stream a HD video from youtube via 3G, play it fullsize, and in the background do some video recording which in parallel gets uploaded via 3G. **CAREFUL !!!** Wear gloves... #-)

Answer (score 3):

The answer is :

- Your phone is charged no matter what.
- But at a slower rate than normal.
- Making it warmer than normal.

Comment: "No" to #1. If your actions require the same or more power than the source can supply, the battery cannot be charged – but it will discharge slower, as the device primarily uses the external power source. "Yes" to the other two points, however ;)

Answer (score -1):

Your phone charges with the normal speed or rate.
And it makes your battery heat up more and nothing else.

Comment: How is your answer different to Parag_Baji's? Also the charging current is split into two parts: The current needed to power the device and what's left goes into the battery. So, it charges **slower** than normal. If you use a power hungry app (e.g. navigation or a 3D game) it may even discharge your phone (at a slower rate though).

Comment: how is my answer different, because i have seen battery full notification while charging and playing heavy game (temple run)

Comment: It depends on your usage. Do a heavy download over LTE, play a power hungry game and set your screen to max brightness and you'll see the effect. Depending on your charger type and the charging circuit in your phone, it will surely slow down charging or may even discharge. My Galaxy Nexus is capped at 1Ampere charging current and does discharge when playing ingress, for example (the phone uses more than 1A to operate, then, ie. 1A from the chrager, the rest is drawn from the battery).

Comment: May be you are right, but I never got low battery alert while charging is on, no matter what I am doing on my phone. At least not in my lg optimus. That's why I wrote above that your battery is always charging when plugged in.

Comment: Yeah, it's just that operating the phone and charging the battery both compete for power from the wall charger and the former gets priority. If the operating power consumption tops the wall chargers supply, the rest *must* be drawn from the battery. Example: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/24232/battery-drains-even-when-plugged-in-while-using-nav-app-on-long-road-trips or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/418/what-causes-battery-to-drain-faster-than-it-can-charge or http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/25008/whats-the-safe-limit-on-charger-output-for-a-galaxy-nexus